# Activate Verizon SIM Card While In Canada

Tags: usa, canada, cellphones

I am in the middle of a long term trip in Canada (~6 Months). Until now I have been using
a Verizon plan which allows me to roam on Canadian networks free of charge. I recently lost my phone and have purchased a new handset, but no longer have my Verizon SIM card. I am able to get a replacement SIM (shipped from family to where I am staying), but I am relatively sure that I will not be able to activate the new SIM in Canada based on this [forum post](https://community.verizon.com/t5/International-Travel/Activate-sim-in-Canada/td-p/1076264).

Is there some way to get an activated Verizon SIM while in Canada? One idea I've had is having a family member activate the SIM card in an old phone before shipping it to me. Would this work?

Comment: @Midavalo the first suggestion you make is what I am asking if anyone knows is feasible. The second suggestion seems out of the question because of the forum response by a Verizon emplyoee, which seems to indicate that they do not have a means of activating a SIM internationally for a customer who lost their phone while traveling.

Comment: My primary concern is that the SIM needs to be activated per-phone, or if there is something related to roaming which will impede swapping the SIM card off of the home network, which some people here may have experience with.

Comment: If it's only Canada, you could ship your phone overnight back to your family member, have them activate it it then ship back to you overnight again.

Comment: How far are you from the US border (and a US Verizon network)? Maybe a quick trip south would do it; you might be able to connect to Verizon in the US without even crossing the border; I've had that experience at the US/Mexico border.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica a bus trip to Buffalo is possible, but annoying. It is a good contingency but not ideal.

Comment: @PeterM, similarly, a good contingency but quite expensive once you consider customs fees for shipping a brand new phone back and forth.

Comment: @HenryPrickettMorgan How much is it worth to you for *not* having your ability to roam in Canada?  And your family member could purchase the handset for you, thus saving money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to contact Verizon and suspend your line immediately (if you haven't already done so).

Second, you need to have an IMEI to activate a Verizon phone.  You should be able to get the IMEI from your new handset.

You can go online (or call Verizon), suspend the current SIM, and order the new SIM using the new phone's IMEI.

Now, I am unsure if SIM can be put into another phone (different IMEI) to activate or if it can be activated in Canada.  However, I believe you could order the new SIM using a family member's IMEI (it would have to be one that is not already registered with Verizon), activate the SIM in that phone, then ship it to you and change the IMEI linked to the phone via the Verizon website.

**Please note!**  The above is untested by me, it is simply my understanding of how the Verizon online portal works.